# How to change Alpine.js x-data value in Google Maps Autocomplete javascript?

Tags: javascript, alpine.js, google-places-autocomplete

I am trying to implement Alpine.js with Google Autocomplete and I couldn't figure out how to make my modal shows up when I clicked on the dropdown result.

How do I set 'myModal' which is false by default in my x-data to be true in the event listener below?

```
    <body>
      <div x-data="{ myModal: false }">
       <input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter a location" 
        autocomplete="on" runat="server" />  

        <div x-show="myModal">
           Content..
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
        function initialize() {
          var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
          var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
                //how to set 'myModal = true' here
            });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this task (mutating Alpine.js state from an external script) you can use the global [`Alpine.store()`](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-store) object. Here we create a small `myModal` store object with a minimal open/close/toggle API and one internal state:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.store('myModal', {
    active: false,

    toggle() {
      this.active = !this.active
    },

    open() {
      this.active = true
    },

    close() {
      this.active = false
    }
  })


  function initialize() {
      var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField')
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input)
      google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        // Open modal window
        Alpine.store('myModal').open()
      })
  }

  initialize()
})
</script>
```

And in the template we access the modal's state like `$store.myModal.active`:

```
<div x-data="">
    <input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter a location" 
        autocomplete="on" runat="server" />  

    <div x-show="$store.myModal.active">
        Modal content...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me this method. This actually make sense. I am currently testing out this method but I ran into an error saying that Alpine.store is not a function when calling inside of the listener. Do you have any idea for this?

Comment: If you are using Alpine.js as a module with a bundler, [add it to the global window object](https://alpinejs.dev/essentials/installation#as-a-module). `window.Alpine = Alpine`. Thus it will available globally.

Comment: i see, this feature is basically unavailable if im using Alpine.js through CDN?

Comment: In the CDN bundle, it global by default, so you have a different issue. Did you put the maps script's `initialize()` function inside a `document.addEventListener('alpine:init', ...` block like in my example? Since Alpine.js' script usually has a `defer` keyword, you need to wrap the components inside an `alpine:init` block in order to wait for Alpine.js' initialization.

Comment: yeah, i was sure that might have been the issue but I have already double checked and I did in fact wrapped everything within the`alpine:init` block

Comment: yeah I even tried copy pasting your code into mine, the same issue still happen

Comment: Do you use the latest v3.x of Alpine.js?

Comment: the Alpine.store works as expected when I tried the piece of code the documentation provided. I am beginning to suspect the issue is from the google autocomplete. Do you think adding a settimeout to solve this issue?

Comment: If you created the maps init function inside an `alpine:init` event block, then `Alpine.store()` global object should be already available. Strange problem.

Comment: yeah, thank you regardless. I think I'll mark your answer as the correct one since technically using Alpine.store() is the right way to handle it. thank you again for your time :)